# who determines what is "not constructive"?

Tags: discussion, not-constructive

For example: I have been on this site for three years and the following question may be the *most useful question I have ever read* on the entire site, and clearly others agree as well:

[Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)

I literally learned more Python in two nights reading every answer to that question than I did in months with books. I'm not trying to simply complain about one post; I've seen other SO posts like this that were "closed as not constructive" that were *extremely useful to learn from*; which to me is the definition of constructive.

So if more than 1400 upvotes and 3000+ favorites is not enough for a question to be "constructive", what is? The 99% of SO questions with one answer, maybe an upvote, that helps one person solve one problem? I would violently argue that if thousands of people think something is helpful then it is "constructive"..

Comment: This has been thrashed to death. These days most of the posts have gone to meta.stackexchange. Start with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked

Comment: It took a long time to bring the crowd around on this, but it eventually became clear to a lot of people just how poisonous those popularity contests are. Thank FSM there will be no more of them.

Comment: I find it extremely ironic that so many meta-stack-overflow posts are about "why are there so many low quality questions on SO blah blah" while questions with 3000 favorites and 1500 upvotes are being closed. Perhaps the "type of question" SO wants to allow are not the type of questions that are useful for a large audience which SO states is its goal. I find the goal and the type of question allowed to be contradictory. How useful is a QA database with a bunch of answers that serve one problem---not very---so why close questions actually useful to a huge audience? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to do some digging, but this question was first authored back in '08.  Back then, the rules of what was and what wasn't on topic were a bit looser, so you get a few questions like that - questions that were considered useful and helpful, but ultimately didn't gel well with the policy changes on questions.

I'm not saying that it isn't useful, and I'm not saying that questions that are similar to it aren't useful either.  But, to put it simply:  **they're not good questions for the site as it stands today**.  There are a lot of these "lesser-known" features of programming languages, and as the language grows and matures, these features become more known, thus invalidating existing answers and creating a cycle of constant fixing of outdated information.

It wasn't really any one person that decided; the community made its call (on several separate occasions, too) to ultimately close the question.  It's definitely got some historical significance, and its answers are still somewhat useful, but again - it was asked and promoted in a different time of Stack Overflow - back when these sorts of questions were OK.

Comment: "back when these sorts of questions were OK"---yet, ironically, most MSO posts today are about "why are there so many bad/low quality questions on SO". Maybe because greatly useful posts are being closed and discouraged.

Answer (score -4):

Well, a "thread" like that is only possible because there are a lot of experts here. And there are only a lot of experts here because of the overall quality and usability of the site. And the quality of the site is maintained through rules like marking a thread like that as "non constructive".

Otherwise, I do agree, but then that is also why that question has been locked/protected rather than deleted. Also, there may be other StackExchange sites that fit that style of question better, <s>such as `programmers.stackexchange.com`</s>.

Comment: Locking such a useful question prevents other extremely useful questions of similar type from appearing. I'm not sure prohibiting the types of questions that generate 1000+ upvotes and 3000+ favorites is "best for quality"; especially since theres a lot of chat here about how many low quality questions there are.

Comment: @Tommy if it wasn't closed, would it still be as high-quality as it is? Once a question like that becomes popular enough, then *everyone* wants to add their two-cents, and at some point it becomes redundant and unnecessary for further contributions to be added. One thing I would disagree with, though, is going through a question like that and weeding out a lot of good answers. IIRC they did that to the "good programming books" question.

Comment: Then perhaps "locked to preserve quality" would be more appropriate if that is your argument. But "locked as not constructive" is so misleading and wrong to me (who learned half the language from the post). I've seen other questions where you need a certain amount of rep to answer; maybe that would be best.

Comment: @Tommy yeah the wording "closed as not constructive" seems misleading, but the separate "locked" part is the "locked to preserve" one. the close reason should be something more like "closed as off-topic".

Comment: Funny how far a little wording goes; if it said "Locked to Preserve Answer Quality" I may never even have posted this. Having said that, who is to say if only 100-rep-within-Python-ers were allowed to post, that even more useful things wouldn't have been posted? I'm not sure I buy the degradation argument and I know I've seen posts where you need rep to post.

Comment: Programmers.SE is *not* for the 'not constructive' or 'thread' like questions.  This is why there is no migration path from SO to P.SE.  Please read [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl). I would also suggest giving [How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/213963) a read for a bit of the history. But, please, no - P.SE is *not* for not constructive.

Comment: @MichaelT k thanks for pointing that out