# Can't deleted comments confuse users who try to enter into a discussion?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I have really thought about that many times ago, specially when i feel most of the time that my deleted-comment will change the context of such a discussion, therefore it might confuse other users.

To my mind, i think it's better, on the one hand, to prevent any user from deleting their own comments, and, on the other hand, we can let user edit his comment whenever he wants (not limited by three minutes). And of course moderators can delete comments due to terms of service violations.

Comment: You should try to search for the topic to understand why it is implemented as it is. It has been discussed over and over again.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294672/is-comment-deletion-affect-my-privileges/294673?noredirect=1#comment195362_294673 - "I'm against this idea" so instead of repeating it again, I express my opinion with a downvote.

Comment: Good, if they do get confused. We don't want discussions.

Comment: @MChaker downvotes don't have to be explained here. They means "I don't find feature useful".

Comment: But i just want to know why can't be like that?

Comment: Too many extraneous comments can *also* confuse users. If a discussion is getting too long and/or comments become obsolete, it's a good thing that they're removed.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but unfortunately, most good features have their negative sides. Deleting own comment is intended when you feel that it's obsolete (e.g. typo clarification). But not limiting edit to 5 minutes can be used to deceive many people (posting a sound argument, get upvotes, and edit to nonsense). In the end, I still don't see the benefits. (Oh, and comments are 2nd-class citizen). Edit: got ninja'd by many comments due to slow typing on mobile ._.

Comment: It seems that a downvote to a question on `meta stackoverflow` has another meaning (i don't see that bad -2 when my question gets downvoted), i think as @MarounMaroun said it means `I don't find feature useful` and it doesn't affect my privileges of asking questions on meta. Am i right?

Comment: @MChaker Meta downvotes are indeed different, and no, you do not lose reputation for downvotes on Meta. Pretty sure you can't be question banned on Meta, since it works so differently, but I don't remember for sure. (Note: None of the above applies to Meta Stack Exchange. All of this applies only to per-site child metas.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing users to edit comments at any time has all the same problems as letting them delete comments, with the additional disadvantage that you lose history when the comments are edited.

Comment history isn't tracked in the same way as post edit history is, so if someone could edit their comments at any time, you'd lose track of what was originally said. This would allow abusive users to post insults and then edit them after the target had seen them, but before moderators did. We'd never know the insults were posted to begin with. We see people trying to do this with comments they post and then delete, but we have a clear record of the deleted comments and can act on those.

Allowing editing of comments at any time won't address the possibility of one side of a conversation potentially going out of sync with another, and won't help with cases where obsolete comments should simply be removed.

Answer (score 5):

One concrete reason to remove a comment is after it has been addressed by an edit.

It is confusing to have comments that refer to a question the way it was "some time ago".    It is helpful to be able to comment, have the comment dealt with by the original poster, then delete the comment because it no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are not meant for prolonged discussion of the question; websites under the Stack Exchange umbrella are *not* forums.
If you want to discuss the question in detail with a user, you should be using the [chatrooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com).

Comments that enter a discussion in order to clarify an aspect of the question should be, once clarified, deleted and the clarification should be edited into the question by its author. If you see a bunch of comments that are a discussion, it'll probably be better to *flag* them as [not-constructive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266623/who-determines-what-is-not-constructive).

For the above reasons I'm going to have to disagree on this one, since *discussion comments should be removed when the discussion is over, anyway*.